# Passing arguments in Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to pass the name of a file as an argument in Process.Start("", ""). However, my parameters don't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1

Public Sub Button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click

    Dim myFile0 As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\1.pdf"
    Dim myFile2 As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\1s.pdf"

    Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k pdftk" & myFile & "output" & myFile2 & "owner_pw password")
```

That does not work, but if I use the file path instead of myFile0 or myFile2 it works fine. 
I need to be able to use the variables.

Any inputs why it doesn`t work. I am new to vb.net

Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much it works. Here is what i did: Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k pdftk " & myFile0 & " output " & myFile2 & " owner_pw password")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting the spaces before and after the file name. Double quotes are also *strongly* recommended to avoid trouble if the path name contains spaces.  This is always easier to get right when you use composite formatting. Fix:

```
Dim args = String.Format("/k pdftk {0}{1}{0} output {0}{2}{0} owner_pw password", _
               """", myFile, MyFile2)
Process.Start("cmd.exe",  args)
```

Answer (score 1):

If just a filepath is specified in the parameters, Process.Start will attempt to launch the file with the default file handler (such as Adobe for PDF files). If you want to launch a specific program with arguments, you should pass the executable path to the program that is handling the .pdf file, with the command line arguments being in the second parameter.

Process.Start(PathToPDFHandler, "/k pdftk" & myFile & "output" & myFile2 & "owner_pw password")

Something like that.