# Executing a program using "Runas"

Tags: c#, vb.net, batch-file

I'm running a `runas` with commands/arguments using .bat and .vbs to bypass an SRP restriction(for educational only), the .vbs file is to hide the command window, how do I write this on VB.Net or C#. I want to make it a standalone .exe file because I want to disallowed also the Command Prompt and VBScript also in the machine using SRP.

**HideBat.vbs**

```
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "run.bat", 0, True
```

**run.bat**

```
    @ ECHO OFF
    runas /trustlevel:"Unrestricted" "C:\Program Files\Deluge\deluged.exe"
```

This is what I come up so far.

```
     Dim myprocess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
     myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.System), "runas.exe")
     myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/trustlevel:"Unrestricted"" & " " & "c:\program.exe"
     myprocess.Start()
```

There is a problem on the `Unrestricted`, because of quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arguments in Process.Start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413125/passing-arguments-in-process-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming C# (I don't know why you tagged this as VB.NET and C#)

```
Process myprocess = new Process();
myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.System), "runas.exe");
myprocess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/trustlevel:\\\"Unrestricted\" \"C:\\Program Files\\Deluge\\deluged.exe\"";
myprocess.Start();
```

Use backslash to escape double quotes inside a string.

Updated answer-forgot to backslash the backslashes in the path.

Comment: thanks I will try it..about the tag, either VB.net or C# will do, again thanks i will try it

Comment: in the arguments there is a blue squiggly line under the Unrestricted up to C